# How to fix "ImportError: PyArrow >= 0.8.0 must be installed; however, it was not found."?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I use PySpark 2.4.0 and when I executed the following code in `pyspark`:

```
$ ./bin/pyspark
Python 2.7.16 (default, Mar 25 2019, 15:07:04)
...
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.0
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.16 (default, Mar 25 2019 15:07:04)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
>>> from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StringType
>>> slen = pandas_udf(lambda s: s.str.len(), IntegerType())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/x/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py", line 2922, in pandas_udf
    return _create_udf(f=f, returnType=return_type, evalType=eval_type)
  File "/Users/x/spark/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py", line 47, in _create_udf
    require_minimum_pyarrow_version()
  File "/Users/x/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 149, in require_minimum_pyarrow_version
    "it was not found." % minimum_pyarrow_version)
ImportError: PyArrow >= 0.8.0 must be installed; however, it was not found.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Is PyArrow really installed ? I have this feeling that the error must be misleading.

Comment: Nope, it was not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message in this case is misleading, `pyarrow` wasn't installed.

From the official documentation [Spark SQL Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#ensure-pyarrow-installed) (that led to [Installing PyArrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html)), you should simply execute one of the following commands:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow
```

or

```
$ pip install pyarrow
```

It is also important to run it under proper user and Python version. I.e., if one is using Zeppelin under root with Python3, it might be needed to execute

```
# pip3 install pyarrow
```

instead

Comment: I have done that but is not working yet. Could it be related to the folder where it is installed?

If I do

 $ pip list

I can see    pyarrow 0.16.0

Comment: same here... when I to pip freeze I get pyarrow==5.0.0. I'm working from jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Re-installing `pyarrow` is what works for me:

```
$ pip uninstall pyarrow -y
$ pip install pyarrow
```

and then restart the kernel.

Comment: I have done that but is not working yet. Could it be related to the folder where it is installed?

If I do

 $ pip list

I can see    pyarrow 0.16.0

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue, but turned out it was a virtual environment issue.

so I run:

```
conda deactivate
conda activate <NAME_OF_VENV>
```

and then I could install normally.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem to get `pyarrow` working with Spark 2.3.
The following solved mine:

1. uninstall pandas since mine coming for deb9 package

   `sudo apt-get remove python-pandas`
2. install pandas (`pandas (0.24.2)`)

   `sudo pip install pandas`
3. install pyarrow (`pyarrow (0.16.0)`):

   `sudo pip install pyarrow`
4. add the following to `spark-env.sh`

   `ARROW_PRE_0_15_IPC_FORMAT=1`
5. restart all workers and masters
6. run `pyspark`

Comment: This part *"restart all workers and masters"* sounds like you use Spark Standalone cluster and you're right they have to be restarted after installing pyarrow for Spark (`pyspark` tool and the nodes).

Answer (score 0):

i met this problem but maybe not relevant to your question. The case is, i use vscode as my IDE, and anaconda as my python compiler. When i run my code, this notification show there. And i solve this issue by install pyarrow in my base environment. Before this, i only install pyarrow in my pyspark virtual env